# Xcode 5 - Storyboard localization

Tags: localization, xcode5

I am developing in Xcode 5 and I am trying to localize me app. There is a bunch of tutorials but nothing specific about Xcode 5.

When I try to localize a storyboard by clicking **Localize** button in *File Inspector* I will get just two options - *Base* and *English*.

I have found out that I can add Localizations item along with some languages under **Project Settings > Info** tab.

But I have still just two options for localization of storyboard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved the problem. After selecting Project in Project Navigator you have to focus on left upper corner. There is a target selected by default. You have to select your project and then you can find Localization section under Info tab. Oh dear..

Hope this helps someone.

[image]

Comment: Just spent two days trying to solve this... And only found your question after I've already typed up my own here on SO. In any case, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I was struggling with this pathetic problem some days as well:). Glad to hear I helped you!

Comment: @strejdashek Oh, thank you guy!!! I have been fighting against windmills for hours, until I found this question+answer from you!